# Objective C NSDictionary from NSString

Tags: objective-c, json

```
@interface users : NSObject {
    NSString *_id;
    NSString *logo;
    NSNumber *longtitude;
    NSNumber *latitude;
}
```

I have NSString:

```
NSString *requestReply = 
{"status":1,"result":[{"id":"150","latitude":"31.7512103","longitude":"35.208157700000015","logo":"http://admin.t-club.co.il/upload/LOGO/150/694.jpg"},{"id":"145","latitude":"31.246028","longitude":"34.80849480000006","logo":"http://admin.t-club.co.il/upload/LOGO/145/689.jpg",},{"id":"37","latitude":"29.5593765","longitude":"34.95099419999997","logo":"http://admin.t-club.co.il/upload/LOGO/37/190.jpg",},{"id":"84","latitude":"29.5512331","longitude":"34.95264959999997","logo":"http://admin.t-club.co.il/upload/LOGO/84/483.jpg"}],"error":0}
```

How can I make array from class users with data from string that I have?

Comment: That is not a valid string. Is that string enclosed in @ " " ? Where is the json response coming from ? Please post complete code.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```